# Password string generation

Tags: strings, bash, linux, unicode, macos

I'm trying to create passwords using the following snippet to match a custom password policy. I've added three `gtr` statements, at the end of the string, to guarantee my password policy is met.

```
foo=$(gtr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 96;
gtr -dc 'A-Z' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1;
gtr -dc 'a-z' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1;
gtr -dc '0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1);
echo $foo
```

Could this code be simplified?

Comment: What does the `gtr` command do?

Comment: The gtr command is the same as tr in Linux, just a Mac specific one that is installed through `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need GNU tr for this task. The macOs tr should work equally well.

For passwords, you should use `/dev/random` instead of `urandom`.

It's a funny password policy if it really requires the password to be 99 characters long. At that length, it doesn't matter anymore whether the password contains a digit or not because such a long password, if generated by a strong random generator, cannot be guessed.

The code in itself is fine. I would indent it differently, though, lining up all *four* calls to `tr`. Writing a function to eliminate the code duplication is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @Roland's review,
I recommend to move the repeated logic of getting `n` random characters to a function.

```
chars() {
    local chars=$1
    local count=$2
    gtr -dc "$chars" < /dev/random | head -c "$count"
}

chars a-zA-Z0-9 96
chars A-Z 1
chars a-z 1
chars 0-9 1
```

Having common logic in a function makes it easier to maintain the code.
For example, following Roland's suggestion to use `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`, you can make the change in one place, instead of many.

And now I also see why you needed to use `gtr` instead of `tr`.
The BSD version of `tr` in OSX would complain about illegal byte sequences.